# Azure Function How To Return XML Not A String

Tags: c#, xml, azure, function

I am trying to return a XML config file from an Azure Function. The config is being written into a string like below.

```
                    xml = @"<note>
                        <to>Tove</to>
                        <from>Jani</from>
                        <heading>Reminder</heading>
                        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                        </note>";
```

I am then returning it like this

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, xml.Replace("\r\n",""));
```

However the result from the HTTP call is like this

```
    "
    <note>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>"
```

How do I get rid of the enclosing quotation marks?

Comment: Have you tried `req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, xml, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter)` ?

Comment: Which package does Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter come from? My VS is saying use System.Configuration but it doesn't have definition for Formatters.XmlFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
var xml = @"<note>
                        <to>Tove</to>
                        <from>Jani</from>
                        <heading>Reminder</heading>
                        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                        </note>";
 return new ContentResult() { Content = xml, ContentType = "text/xml"};
```

Comment: If I try that I get

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Comment: @JonFarmer what Target Framework are you using for your function? You can check this in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of setting the Content-Type of the request and then send as a string. This method that has been working in production. This is how to return XML from an Azure Function Net7 isolated:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    
    var xml = @"<note>
                        <to>Tove</to>
                        <from>Jani</from>
                        <heading>Reminder</heading>
                        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                        </note>";
    
    HttpResponseData? response;
    response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    await response.WriteStringAsync(xml);   

    return response;
    
}
```